# Python to exe with ffmpeg

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I made a python script (one application folder containing: 4 folders with data like images etc for the gui but also empty folders, needed to run the app and 4 extra .py files). Now the problem, I want to be able to send my app to people so they can just install it on their PC without having to install python etc. I also need FFMPEG (which also has to be added to the environment variables (C:\ffmpeg\bin). I already checked out pyinstaller (+NSIS) and auto-py-to-exe but it just doesn't want to work. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Seems to be the solution: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2470